# Fast algorithm for finding a small picture in big picture?

Tags: .net, algorithm, image-processing, image

**what would be the best (fastest) way to check if a small picture is inside a big picture?**

(Zoomed picture:)

[image] Want to Find:
[image]

I have a solution, but it is very slow:

- i iterate through every single pixel (x,y) in the big picture and compare the pixel (0,0) of the small picture (color value).
- if the pixel is the same, I iterate through the small picture and compare it with the bigger one.. if it fails, it goes back to the big picture scanning loop..

this method needs like ~7 seconds to find a 50x50 pic on 1600x1200 photo.

maybe you know a better algorithm? i know a software which can do this in under a second.

Comment: Consider it a string matching. There are several fast string matching algorithms available. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm.

Comment: @Captain The reduction to string matching is nontrivial, however. I’m doing a lot of work with string matching and I don’t see an obvious, efficient reduction (I have some ideas but they are not at all obvious).

Comment: @Konrad I was thinking, one line of pixels per string both for needle and haystack, but you might be quite right about it being nontrivial.

Comment: Your algorithm shouldn't be THAT slow.  I suspect you're not accessing the two image buffers directly (and calling some GetPixel() function instead).  If you're unsure how to do that, post your code + 2 pics, and we can help.

Comment: Do you get a completely new image each time you do this, or are you working with a series of frames that are mostly identical? If the latter, things like quadtrees can make this a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mathematical operation [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) (which can be efficiently implemented with the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_Transform)) can be used for this.

Comment: To clarify Aasmund answer. You do a convolution (haar wavelet transform could also work) of your target image and with that you obtain a result. Then you do a convolution of the source image and try to find potential candidate results. Most of the time it will point you in the right direction with far less information to compare.

Comment: Isn't the running time of an FFT ~O(N Log N) larger than that of a linear search? This would be useful if you were doing repeated searches on the same large image.

Comment: @Red Knight and Aasmund - If you use a FFT to do convolution, how can you determine if the target image and the source image are matching? I feel like it is similar to string matching as suggested by others.

Comment: @LastCoder: A "linear" search (in one dimension) runs in _O(n*m)_, where _m_ is the length of the pattern - so FFT is better unless _m_ is very small.

Comment: @O_O: I'm a little rusty on the details since it's a while since I've been doing these kinds of things, but: A convolution operation (no matter how it's implemented) takes two images as input and produces a new image where the brightness in location _(x, y)_ tells how well the images would match if the corner of the second image was placed at _(x, y)_ on the first image. So you could simply locate the brightest pixel, which would tell you how much you need to shift the image.

Answer (score 1):

the other answer describes cross-correlation via convolution of images (implemented by multiplying ffts).  but sometimes you want to use *normalized* cross-correlation - see http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.html for a full discussion and details of a fast implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the pixel values will be exact, this just becomes a special case of a string matching problem. There are lots of fast string matching algorithms, I'd start with [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm) or [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: This answer is great when combined with [Simone's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7337521/1227469).

Answer (score 1):

You're algo has a worst case of `O(hA*wA*hB*wB)` where `hA`,`wA`,`hB`,`wB` are height and width of the big image `A` and the small image `B`.

This algo should instead have a worst case of `O((wA+wB)*hA*hB)`

It's based on string matching and this is how it works:

- Find each row of the image `B` in each row of image `A` using string matching each time.

  - Every time you have a match, store in the array `matched_row` a triple `(rA, cA, rB)` where `(rA, cA)` represents the starting point in the image `A` of the `rB` row of the file `B`.
- Now you sort `matched_row` first according to `cA`, then to `rA` and then to `rB`.
- Now you iterate the array and if you matched an image B of 5 row you will have something like this:

  ```
      (12, 5, 0), (13, 5, 1), (14, 5, 2), (15, 5, 3), (15, 5, 4)
  ```

Comment: "Now we simply match stringB against stringA" -- Could you explain this?  stringB contains dummy characters.  I don't think this works.